# C++ Accessors - should I return a pointer to the member variable or the actual member variable itself?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, member, accessor

I have what is hopefully a simple question here.  For my member variables of my classes, all of which are private, should I use accessors to return a pointer or return the variable itself?  Or should I be doing something else?

Example:

```
unsigned int *Object::GetObjectIDPointer()
{
    return &objectID;
}
```

OR

```
unsigned int Object::GetObjectID()
{
    return objectID;
}
```

Comment: The best way is to avoid accessors.

Comment: Dont't name it GetXxxxPointer when it returns a non-pointer.

Comment: @harper That was a minor copy-paste typo when I made the question. ><

Comment: Your first example in effect makes the "private" variable public, which is contrary to the point of `private`.

Answer (score 4):

This depends a lot on what you would like to do with them: if you plan the users of your class to be able to modify variables inside your class (a terrible and strongly discouraged thing) you can return pointers or references; otherwise, return the variable itself.

There is an exception to this rule when objects that you'd like to return are large, such as vectors, sets, maps, etc. If you decide to make accessors to them, you should return them by constant reference.

Comment: I disagree.  One should almost never return a pointer to a member, nor return by value from a getter function.  Return references and const references almost always.

Comment: @MooingDuck I follow this rule and return references when I write my template code, but in non-template code I make decisions case-by-case. For example, I return `int` by value rather than by const reference for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, take the second solution.
More generally, you can return a copy of the object itself, the compiler is likely to optimize out any unnecessary copies with the [copy elision optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

You can also return a const reference to the field:

```
const MyType& getMyField() const { return this->myField; }
```

That way, no copies are created and the value can't be modified (except with `const_cast`).

But for an int, I think you should return a copy, as in your second solution:

```
unsigned int Object::GetObjectIDPointer()
{
    return objectID;
}
```

Comment: returning references, however, can be dangerous. Callers may save a reference, too (`const MyType& m = something.getMyField();`), which might become dangling.

Comment: @phresnel: pointers have the same problem, and the workarounds can be very slow.  Returning by reference is the best option. olchauvin: RVO only helps when you return a local variable.  When returning a member, it still has to do a full copy.

Comment: @MooingDuck You are right, I meant "copy elision". I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to get the value, then return by value. Also, declare the function `const`. However, if it's large or expensive to copy, it might be better to return a `const` reference so that the caller can choose not to make a copy of it.

If you also want to be able to modify it, then either return a reference (or a pointer if you like), or provide a "set" function. Alternatively, just make it public - there's not much point in pretending that it's encapsulated when it isn't.

If you do return a reference (or pointer), then make sure you have a `const` overload, otherwise you won't be able to read the value from `const` objects:

```
const unsigned int *Object::GetObjectIDPointer() const
{
    return &objectID;
}
```

Comment: I disagree.  One should almost never return a pointer to a member, nor return by value from a getter function.  Return references and const references almost always.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Depends on the type, as I said. Returning small POD types (like the one in the question) by value is usually faster and safer than by reference; and I suggested that references are preferable to pointers, but don't want to dictate style if the OP prefers pointers.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your method

```
GetObjectIDPointer()
```

if it is private method then use pointer, as it will make your member accessibility fast. but If the method is public you should always return a copy. As if you return a pointer it will breach basic principles of OOPS(Data hiding).

Comment: returning a member by pointer in a private function is just silly.